# How to create a shape with a gradient fill, and add it to a border background in WPF

Tags: wpf, background, shapes, linear-gradients

I am trying to create the following shape as a background to a border. You will notice that the bottom section on the shape has a linear gradient to it.

I have played around with lines and shapes and gradients, but i have not been able to apply the below to a border. nor can i get a shape that looks like that.

Is this even possible? if so, can anyone help

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below XAML produces a brush that looks similar to your picture. You should play around the colors, offsets, and the rest for the best appearance.

```
<DrawingBrush x:Key="br1" Viewbox="0,0,100,100" ViewboxUnits="Absolute" >
  <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    <DrawingGroup>
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="Lavender">
          <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
              <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,100,100" />
          </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
        </GeometryDrawing>
        <GeometryDrawing>
            <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.5,0.01" Center="0.5,-0.2" RadiusX="100">
                    <GradientStop Color="MidnightBlue" Offset="1.0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="LightSteelBlue" Offset="0.0" />
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
          <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
              <EllipseGeometry Center="60,310" RadiusX="160" RadiusY="300" />
          </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
        </GeometryDrawing>
    </DrawingGroup>
  </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

Have fun!

Comment: @Mario Vernari, wow, i am seriously impressed here. this is EXACTLY what i was looking for. How did you go about creating the brush? did you make use of Expression Design, or is there some place i can learn more about "Gradient Origins", and "ViewBoxes"?

Comment: Well, I used Blend just for a quick tuning, but I never use for the everyday job. About docs, here you may find some *basic* example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749021(v=vs.110).aspx

However, I'd recommend to take a look at the SVG specs. SVG is NOT XAML, but they're sharing several common concepts, which should help you to understand better many aspects of the vector graphics: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns